Searching for specific integer string mix instance in Python
I am trying to find the instance of "2.22 / 2.22 GiB" where the integers are variables.
I have tried:
size_re = re.compile("[0-9]+.[0-9][0-9] / [0-9]+.[0-9][0-9] GiB")

def download_size(output):
    m = size_re.search(output)
    if m:
        sizegroup = m.group()
        return int(sizegroup)

However, I have been unable to get one hit.

Are you trying to look for a line where the same (unknown) number appears twice, or a line with two unknown numbers?

Please show some examples of strings that this regular expression doesn't match.

You're applying int() to the entire match - which includes multiple non-numeric characters.  A ValueError is what I'd expect from this code.

Just as a recommendation: regex101.com is a great website to test your regex patterns and even supports a variety of different regex engines.

You can use this pattern instead:
[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?\s*\/\s*[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?\s*GiB

or
([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\s*\/\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\s*GiB

if you want to capture the 2.22s.
Code
import re

def download_size(output):
    size_re = r'([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\s*\/\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\s*GiB'
    a, b = re.findall(size_re, output)[0]
    return a, b

print(download_size('2.22 / 2.22 GiB'))


Prints
('2.22', '2.22')


Note:

() is a capturing group, which creates a copy of anything inside it in the memory.

(?:) is a non-capturing group, which simply creates a group without any copy in the memory.

([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?): has an optional non-capture group, in case there is no floating part. (e.g., 2 and 5.9 are both valid).

* means zero or more times and + means one or more times.



We consider all the following strings valid:
2/2GiB
2.22/2.22GiB
2.22   / 2.22 GiB
2.22 /      2.22GiB
2.22    /        2.22          GiB


You could write \d instead of [0-9]

@lord_haffi In this case, \d is fine. But, [0-9] and \d are different. See.

I solved this after relooking at the output string and realized that at times it enters either MiB or Kib after the first set of digits.
size_re = re.compile("[0-9]+.[0-9][0-9] (.*)iB / [0-9]+.[0-9][0-9] GiB")
alt_size_re = re.compile("[0-9]+.[0-9][0-9] / [0-9]+.[0-9][0-9] GiB") 

def download_size(output):           
    m = size_re.search(output)       
    a = alt_size_re.search(output)   
    if m:                            
        sizegroup = m.group()      
        return sizegroup           
    if a:                            
        sizegroup = a.group()      
        return sizegroup


import re

def get_size(text_to_search):
    regex = r"(\d+\.?(\d+)?)\s+/\s+(\d+\.?(\d+)?)\s+GiB"
    match = re.match(regex, text_to_search)
    if match is not None:
        return (match.group(1), match.group(3))

print(get_size("2.22 / 2.23 GiB"))
print(get_size("2 / 3 GiB"))
print(get_size("2.0 / 3 GiB"))
print(get_size("2.0 / 3.0 GiB"))

Output:
('2.22', '2.23')
('2', '3')
('2.0', '3')
('2.0', '3.0')

The above piece of code will work for your requirement. It also takes care of cases where there may not be a decimal point used in the ratio.
